# How to switch CSV Datasource based on the input control?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have developed a *JasperReports* report using csv datasource and successfully published on *JasperReports Server*.

Question : Now, I want switch the csv datasources based on the parameter (abc).

- When parameter value "csv1" is selected by the user ----> sample.jrxml should connect to "path of csv1"
- When parameter value "csv2" is selected by the user ----> sample.jrxml should connect to "path of csv2"

Note : I am not using tables in sample.jrxml file

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a CSV file as the source for your data, you could do something like this in your JRXML:

```
<parameter name="switchParam" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["abc"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.csv.source" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{switchParam} == "abc" ? "path/to/CsvDataSource1" : "path/to/CsvDataSource2"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

The CSV source can be passed in either as a property or a parameter, in your case the parameter offering more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the same but when I publishing report on jasper server its resulting an error  " the report is empty" . I think we need to pass something in "Default Data Adapter"

Comment: And it will be really helpful if you could attach the full source of the jrxml.

Comment: Please edit your question and post some sample files(jrxml, dataAdapter, csv with sample data) so that I can better understand what you are doing. Also, please mention the versions(including ce or pro) of your tools: JasperReports, Jaspersoft Studio, JasperReports Server.